# working with a google doc locally in java

Tags: java, report, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to merge string replacements in a google doc template.
Basically similar to this code snippet:
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/merge

The requirement of the project is that there is no discrete date on the google drive, but only the dummy variables for replacement. So you can still change the layout and appearance of the template.
This is part of a basic report component, where project data gets interpolated.

There is the possibility to export the google doc from the drive service

```
String fileId = "1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().export(fileId, "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json")
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

and there is a json representation of the document.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats

My question is:
Can I perform the String var replacements locally and export the document to pdf at runtime?
Is this an expected use case of the google api?

Thank you for your time!
If there is anything I missed, let me know!

Comment: Do you mean exporting the file to your local device, editing the exported file ([merging some text](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/merge)), and then uploading it again? No, I don't think that's possible. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Uploading the file is not necesary. I only need to export the local doc to pdf after the string replacements. Costumer related data can't be on the google cloud.

Comment: To ask more specifically: Can I manipulate the content of the google doc on my local device? Or is there no OOXML like representation?

Comment: I'm unaware if there are tools you can use in Java to modify this locally, but certainly not with Docs API. Also, if you want to download a Google Doc, you should be using one of Docs' supported MIME types: see [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats). The MIME type you're using (`application/vnd.google-apps.script+json`) refers to Apps Script documents.